# How to plot a plotly scattermapbox with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I’m trying to plot lat/lon points on a scattermapbox with a geojson file. I threw the geojson file in a panada’s data frame and made an empty list for lat and lon since thats all scattermapbox accepts. It didn’t turn out as expected.

[image]

**Python Plotly:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

geojson = json.load(open("Data/High Comfort Bike Lanes.geojson"))
geojson = json_normalize(geojson['features'], sep="_")

lon_comfortBike = []
lat_comfortBike = []

for l1 in geojson['geometry_coordinates']:
    for l2 in l1:
        for l3 in l2:
            lon_comfortBike.append(l2[0])
            lat_comfortBike.append(l2[1])

fig = go.Figure(
       data=[
            go.Scattermapbox(
            name='High Comfort Bike Route',
            hoverinfo='name',
            lat=lat_comfortBike,
            lon=lon_comfortBike,
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(width=3, color="#F00")
            ]
        )
    mapLegend = go.layout.Legend(
            x=0,
            y=1,
            traceorder="normal",
            font=dict(
                family="sans-serif",
                size=12,
                color="black"
            ),
            bgcolor="LightSteelBlue",
            bordercolor="Black",
            borderwidth=2
        )

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=True,
    legend=mapLegend,
    margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0},
    mapbox=go.layout.Mapbox(
        style="stamen-terrain", 
        zoom=12, 
        center_lat = 40.55,
        center_lon = -105.08,
    )
)
fig.show()
```

**Python Dataframe:**

```
0      [[[-105.077274, 40.514625], [-105.077005, 40.5...
1      [[[-105.024284, 40.509791], [-105.024274, 40.5...
2      [[[-105.087928, 40.578187], [-105.087939, 40.5...
3      [[[-105.11976, 40.589318], [-105.11977, 40.587...
4      [[[-105.083718, 40.568761], [-105.08459, 40.56...
                             ...
995    [[[-105.05362, 40.525161], [-105.053607, 40.52...
996    [[[-105.030003, 40.62114], [-105.030012, 40.62...
997    [[[-105.123316, 40.560645], [-105.123353, 40.5...
998    [[[-105.070162, 40.580083], [-105.070175, 40.5...
999    [[[-105.120617, 40.560044], [-105.120637, 40.5...
Name: geometry_coordinates, Length: 1000, dtype: object
```

Any suggestions on how to loop through the data frame correctly and plot these lines?

Comment: What do you mean by _extract_, can you be more specific? Also, sharing screenshots is discouraged, please only do so if the nature of the information means it cannot easily be shared as text. It would be good to be able to try things out with your data, too.

Comment: Post has been edited. Thank you for clarifying what I should have fixed. By extraction, I mean how to correctly call lat/lon coordinates from the dataframe so I can plot the line in plotly.

Comment: Isn’t that what you already wrote, though? Can you be a bit more specific, which part of the process (have you broken it down?) is the issue?

Comment: The problem is I have a linestring as my geometry type and I don't know how to plot this specific geometry type in plotly scattermapbox. Plotly only accepts a lat and a lon coordinate and not pairs of them as seen under my plotly header. I tried creating a row of lat and a row of lons in my panadas dataframe but that did not work either.

Comment: What's a _linestring_? I'm still not sure I understand the issue, sorry.

Comment: A linestring is a type of geometry in a geojson file. For instance, a point is just [-105.077274, 40.514625]. but a linestring is a list of points that connect together to form a line. [[-105.077274, 40.514625], [-105.077005, 40.59934]]. Each index in my data frame is a line. This is what I'm trying to plot in the scatterboxmap. Lon and lat are seperate attributes so I'm confused how to plot them. I made a list of all my lats and all my lons, added them to the attributes and as you can see the map didn't turn out well. I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: What do you mean by _Lon and lat are separate attributes_? Do you mean **parameters**?

Comment: Hmm okay I saw the explanation at the top of your post, it seems like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So using pandas with plotly scattermapbox is a headache. This is how I extracted the coordinates from the geojson file to be plotted in the `lat` and `lon` parameters of `go.Scattermapbox`.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import json

geojson = json.load(open("Data/lanes.geojson"))

points = []

for  feature in geojson['features']:
    if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
        points.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])    
        points.append([None, None]) # mark the end of a polygon   
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
        for polyg in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
            points.extend(polyg[0])
            points.append([None, None]) #end of polygon
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiLineString': 
        points.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
        points.append([None, None])
    else: pass   

lons, lats = zip(*points)  

fig = go.Figure(
        go.Scattermapbox(
            name='High Comfort Bike Lane',
            hoverinfo='name',
            lat=lats,
            lon=lons,
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(width=3, color="#F00")
        )
```